# C# create autocomplete with LIKE

Tags: c#, autocomplete

i am trying to create an autocomplete with able to suggest an item where that item contains what i typed.

like this

[image]

but i am implement this autocomplete not in textbox instead in dategridview's cell.

this is my code..

```
     private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {    
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                string gkey = "";
                Connection.ConnectionClose();
                Connection.ConnectionOpen();
                int currentRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
                //TODO fill Customer list
                //string queryItem = "SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE CODE LIKE '%" + dataGridView1.Rows[currentRow].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "%'";
                string queryItem ="";
                //Console.WriteLine("asdf = " + );
                try
                {
                    gkey = dataGridView1.Rows[currentRow].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    queryItem = "SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE CODE LIKE '*" + gkey + "*'";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    gkey = "";
                    queryItem = "SELECT * FROM ITEM ";
                }

                Console.WriteLine("qyery = "+queryItem);
                Connection.command = new OleDbCommand(queryItem, Connection.conn);
                Connection.command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                AutoCompleteStringCollection kode = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
                reader = Connection.command.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows == true)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        kode.Add(reader["code"].ToString());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data not Found");
                }
                reader.Close();
                //ComboBox txtBusID = e.Control as ComboBox;
                TextBox kodeTxt = e.Control as TextBox;
                if (kodeTxt != null)
                {
                    kodeTxt.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                    kodeTxt.AutoCompleteCustomSource = kode;
                    kodeTxt.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                }

            }
}
```

how to implement an autocomplete like the image on above, where this autocomplete can use "LIKE", similar in sql query

for example..

[image]

this image... that list appear when i type "SAM", but when i type "AM" that list is no longer appar.

[image]

Comment: Please include the problem and question.

Comment: Data grid view screen shot also add for useful for visualization.@akiong

Comment: @Saravanakumar see my update question

Comment: @juharr no, see my update question

Comment: @Crowcoder see my update question

Comment: Everything I see uses `%` for the wildcard, not `*`, even with OleDB provider.

Comment: The gist of the matter is, textbox autocomplete doesn't work like that. Even if you populate the items you want to see, the textbox will only display suggestions based on the prefix you already typed, and that behavior can't be changed as far as I can tell. You'll need a different control, like a combobox that you fully control.

Comment: @Crowcoder i tried, but that one is not working. i am using Ms.Access

Comment: @AlexPaven ComboBox with typing style not available in datagridview. :(

Comment: Although I haven't worked with winforms in a long time, I'm pretty sure you can create a custom column type that can contain whatever you want. If the built-in column types don't do what you want, I'm afraid that would be the solution.

Comment: @AlexPaven maybe, i just download this project https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/251110/AutoComplete-TextBox-with-substing-search-similar but i don't know how to paste that control and implement to my datagridview :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override the following method:

dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing

Here is a further explanation: http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/autogridview.htm

Comment: i tried this one..but  `that list appear when i type "SAM", but when i type "AM" that list is no longer appear.`

so  if my item is "SAMSUNG NOTE1" and i type. "NOTE" , this item is not showing

Comment: @akiong, Have a look here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/251110/AutoComplete-TextBox-with-substing-search-similar.  That should help you.

Comment: i tried to,, i already download that project, just don't know how to copy that control to my solution :(